# class and static variables

Tags: c++, static

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    static int a;
    A() {a=1;a++;}

};
int A::a =1;

int main(void){
 A a;

 cout<<A.a<<endl;
 cout<<a<<endl;
 cout<<a.a<<endl;


 return 0;
 }
```

I'm a beginner to C++ and studying class now. I'm just wondering why can I only print out the last one(a.a)? What are the problems for A.a and a? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To print a to need to overload operator <<. To acces a static member with the class definition use  A::a (not A.a)

Comment: @Lingxiao Zhang see my answer below and comment if you have any further queries.Don't forget to accept the answer and give an upvote if it useful

Answer (score 1):

> What are the problems for A.a and a?

`A` is a type, but operator `.` is only applicable to objects (or references to them). If you want to access static variable use different syntax:

```
std::cout << A::a;
```

As for why `std::cout << a` does not work, `std::ostream` does not know how to output instance of class `A`, you can create your own operator for that:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const A &a )
{
   return out << a.a;
}
```

then this code in main will work:

```
std::cout << a;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    cout<<A.a ;//invalid in c++ but valid in java and 
               //some other languages
```

is not a valid syntax and you have to use A::a (pronounced as scope resolution (in the scope of class A))

```
   cout<<A::a ;//valid in c++

 cout<<a; //Here a is an instance that has some 
          //characteristics
```

So you have to use [stream insertion overloading in c++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generic-tree-level-order-traversal/)  to overcome that.

Finally,

```
        cout<<a.a; //well and good as it an attribute of class A.
```

Moreover ,it is a static attribute(shared by other objects).Changes made to that reflects to other objects characteristics.Refer [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-keyword-cpp/)

One final suggestion is to refer good oops concept book.

Answer (score 0):

You have an instance of `A` that you named `a`.

The first line is syntactically wrong because you want to access a static field through the type. In C++, it's written `A::a`.

On the second line, you want to print the instance of `A`, not the content of its field. Since you did not define a way to print an instance of `A`, the build fails. (You will see streams later I guess).

And eventually, the last line is fine because you can access a static field by an instance as well.

Answer (score 0):

`A.a` is not valid, because left operand of the dot operator must be object, not a type. `A::a` would be valid syntax for that.

`std::cout<<a;` actually translates to a call of the function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,[can be const] A& a)` and there isn't one, so the compiler doesn't know how to print object of type `A`. You can implement that function e.g.:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const A& a)
{
    out<<"Hello, I'm object A\n";
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your posted code:

```
 cout<<A.a<<endl;
```

The above line is syntactically incorrect, you should write it as `A::a`

```
cout<<a<<endl;
```

The above line is trying to de-reference an object (Instance of Class A) and the compiler doesn't know how to print.

```
 cout<<a.a<<endl;
```

This prints because here you are correctly accessing a static variable via an instance of class A.